# Cannot pass variable to page definition

Tags: plugins, php

In developing a plugin, a variable `$staging_site` is assigned a value, e.g., `$staging_site = 'some_value'` in the plugin's php file. Later in the same file a function is defined as

```
function stl_page($stagingSite) {
    $url = get_site_url();

    $allowed = strpos($url, $stagingSite) > 0;
    ...
}
```

Further context:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'stl_action_page');

function stl_action_page($stagingSite) {
    add_submenu_page(
            'tools.php', 'STL Update', 'STL Update', 'manage_options', 'update_live', ['stl_page', 'stagingSite' => $stagingSite]);
    add_action('admin_footer', 'stl_script');
}
```

Yet the following appears when the plugin is accessed in admin:

> Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called:

`add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'STL Update', 'STL Update', 'manage_options', 'update_live', ['stl_page', 'stagingSite' => $stagingSite]);`

Note that the 6th parameter you passed was `['stl_page', 'stagingSite' => $stagingSite]` which is not a `callable` type, and a `callable` is expected.

`callable` can be:

- `'function_name'`
- `[ $object, 'method_name' ]`
- `[ 'class', 'static_method_name' ]`
- `function() { /* I'm a lambda/closure/anonymous function yay */ }`

In your case it expected the second thing in the array to be a string containing a function name, instead it got this:

`'stagingSite' => $stagingSite`

and had no idea what to do with it. It doesn't make a lot of sense, especially since the `admin_menu` action doesn't pass a parameter, so there will never be a `$stagingSite`.

So remove the `$stagingSite` argument in your function, and pass a proper `callable` value telling WP what to call to display that submenu page.

As a sidenote, I suspect you did this to pass a variable through to the function, you can't do that via callables, nor should you need to in this scenario